# Get auction proxy bids and used bids data from 2 tables using JOINing

Tags: mysql

I have table p proxy bids and table b bids:

Table p (Proxy):

```
id user_id auction_id max_amount
1      2        1           4
2      4        3           5
3      2        1           2
4      5        2           3
5      2        5           3
6      2        5           5
```

Table b (Bids):

```
id user_id  auction_id bid_amount is_automatic
1      2          1          0.1       1
2      4          1          0.1       1
3      2          1          0.2       1
4      2          4          0.1       0
5      4          3          0.3       1
6      2          1          0.1       1
```

What I want to get is the sum of proxy bids from table p AND the total sum of automatic bids from table b PER user_id and auction_id:

So for user 2, auction 1, result would be something like this:

```
user_id auction_id proxy_sum bids_sum
   2        1           6       0.4
```

Same way, for user 4, auction 3, result would be something like this:

```
user_id auction_id proxy_sum bids_sum
   4        3           5       0.3
```

Same way, for user 5, auction 2, result would be something like this:

```
user_id auction_id proxy_sum bids_sum
   5        2          3       0
```

So far I have this query:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE( SUM( p.max_amount ), 0 ) AS proxy_max, 
    COALESCE( SUM( b.bid_amount ), 0 ) AS proxy_used 
FROM 
    p 
LEFT JOIN 
    b 
ON 
    p.auction_id = b.auction_id 
WHERE 
    b.member_id = "2" 
    AND 
    b.auction_id = "5" 
    AND 
    b.is_automatic = "1"
```

The problem is that if there is not row in table b for a given user_id and auction_id, it does not return the sum of the proxy, and I need the sum of the proxy regardless. For example in the query above for user 5, auction 2, it returns:

```
user_id auction_id proxy_sum bids_sum
   2        5          0       0
```

I need it to return the sum of the proxy regardless like this:

```
user_id auction_id proxy_sum bids_sum
   2        5          8       0
```

Comment: Move the WHERE condiotions to the ON clause. They are converting your LEFT JOIN to an INNER JOIN.

Comment: There should be tables `users` and `auctions`.

Comment: Yes there is a table users, is that needed for the query results I am trying to accomplish? Proxy bids information?